# PrimeNG <p-table> and <p-calendar> icon's not showing after Refresh in Internate Explorer (IE7,11)

Tags: html, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

PrimeNG  and  icon's not showing after Refresh in Internate Explorer (IE7,11) almost all IE Browser Versions.

But in local it is working fine while I am using same IE.
But in Production environment I am getting this error as you can seen in given below image :

Image Might not show as some restriction 
 but the icon in Table like

before refers

```
<< <  1 2 3 4 5 > >>
```

after refresh

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

same thing happens with PrimeNG 
there icone is gone too

[image]

Comment: Is there any error in requests to get those icons?

Comment: @KelvinLai no there is no error just those icone is gone once refresh the page

Comment: same issue i also faced in my Production Environment this issue with primeNG component i also need help if anybody can give some answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have got some Solution which is working fine as it is some compatibility issue with IE browsers

in index.html: in Head tag we have to add given below meta and link tags

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
```