# IE broswer compatibility issue with: Prime-ng Icons, Font-Awesome Icons and Clarity html

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome, primeng, primeng-datatable, vmware-clarity

In my Front-End I have used Prime-ng, Font-awesome and Clarity-icons.
Everything is working fine with Chrome.
Earlier all those feature was visible in IE 11.

**But recently in IE 11.2363 Prime-ng Paginator icons, Clarity icons, Font-awesome icons are not visible**

I have gone through this link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978699/primeng-p-table-and-p-calendar-icons-not-showing-after-refresh-in-internate
```

And some other links and added given links to `index.html`, but it's not working.

I also got a solution (though not verified with my code ) to change security settings in IE which I think should be the last solution to work-area.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

From Linux box it will work fine. Including AWS server.